# What is the distribution of a r.v. if the reciprocal is distributed gamma?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, gamma-distribution

I want to find the posterior distribution of σ^2 when (X1, X2, ..., Xn) ~ N(μ,σ^2), μ is known, and 1/(σ^2) ~ Gamma(α,β), but I'm not sure how to find the prior of σ^2 given the prior of 1/(σ^2). Thanks.

Comment: "Inverse gamma" dist'n.

Comment: Thanks! Seems rather obvious, I don't know how I didn't think of it lol.